# regression model prediction

Tags: regression

I had a regression model, with y being the price of car and response variable being the profit. so now, I need to make a decision whether selling 10 cars of 10,000 value will give me a mimimum profit of 20,000 or one 100,000 car. the linearity is positive ie as price of car increaseso the profit increases.

so I took the predicted profit from.the fit and applied RMSE, root square mean error, to get the range of profitprediction for car valued 10,000 dollars but how can I expand this one car prediction to 10 cars.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated.  What kind of data do you have?

Comment: The question is good--but your procedure looks inappropriate.  That is because the prediction interval depends on more than the RMSE: it also depends on the uncertainty in the regression fit.  An interval for the sum of ten independent responses will depend on ten *correlated* uncertainty estimates, because every one of those ten involves the *same* uncertain fit.